# Como criar um ArrayList com método construtor com String

Tags: java, apache, netbeans, arraylist

Olá, eu gostaria de saber como eu poderia adicionar essas variáveis dentro desse ArrayList.

O programa diz que não é possível por String na Publication, já tentei casting e não deu.

Desde já agradeço.

---

**A questão passada pelo professor:**
Na classe AcademicLibrary, definir um método construtor que receba como parâmetro
valores para os atributos name, description e creationDate. Dentro deste construtor, inicializar os atributos correspondentes da classe com os valores passados e também instanciar um ArrayList chamado publications para armazenar a lista de publicações da biblioteca.

---

**Classe AcademicLibrary:**

```
public class AcademicLibrary implements ILibrary{

    //Atributes:
    private String name;
    private String description;
    private String creationDate;
    private ArrayList<Publication> publications;
    private ArrayList<User> users;

    //Operations:
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getCreationDate() {
        return creationDate;
    }

    public void setCreationDate(String creationDate) {
        this.creationDate = creationDate;
    }

    public ArrayList<Publication> getPublications() {
        return publications;
    }

    public void setPublications(ArrayList<Publication> publications) {
        this.publications = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public ArrayList<User> getUsers() {
        return users;
    }

    public void setUsers(ArrayList<User> users) {
        this.users = users;
    }

    @Override
    public void addPublication(Publication p) {
        publications.add(p);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean removePublication(long id) {
        publications.remove(id);
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public ArrayList<Publication> getAllPublication() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public short countPublications() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public Publication findPublication(String title) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasPublication(String title) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }

    //Methods:
    public AcademicLibrary(String name, String description, String creationDate) {
        this.name = name;
        this.description = description;
        this.creationDate = creationDate;

        ArrayList<Publication> publication;
        
        publication = new ArrayList<>();

        publication.add(this.name, this.description, this.creationDate); // esse não está funcionando


    }
}
```

---

**Classe Publication:**

```
public abstract class Publication {
    
    //Atributes:
    private String title;
    private short year;
    private byte volume;
    private ArrayList<Author> authors;
    
    //Operations:

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public short getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(short year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

    public byte getVolume() {
        return volume;
    }

    public void setVolume(byte volume) {
        this.volume = volume;
    }

    public ArrayList<Author> getAuthors() {
        return authors;
    }

    public void setAuthors(ArrayList<Author> authors) {
        this.authors = authors;
    }
    
}
```

---

**Classe de Teste:**

```
public class Tester {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    
        AcademicLibrary book1 = new AcademicLibrary(input.next(),input.next(),input.next());
        
        System.out.println(book1.getName());
        System.out.println(book1.getDescription());
        System.out.println(book1.getCreationDate());
        
        System.out.println(book1.getPublications()); // não funciona  
    }
}
```

---

**Mensagem de Erro:**

```
    Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
X:\UNIJUI\4º Semestre\Linguagem de Programação I\exercicios netbeans\digital-library\src\com\acme\avaliacaoII\AcademicLibrary.java:114: error: no suitable method found for add(String,String,String)
        publication.add(this.name, this.description, this.creationDate); // esse não está funcionando
    method ArrayList.add(Publication,Object[],int) is not applicable
      (argument mismatch; String cannot be converted to Publication)
    method ArrayList.add(Publication) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    method ArrayList.add(int,Publication) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
1 error
BUILD FAILED (total time: 1 second)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public AcademicLibrary(String name, String description, String creationDate) {
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
    this.creationDate = creationDate;

    ArrayList<Publication> publications = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Quando você cria o AcademicLibrary a lista de publicações estará vazia. Para preencher basta criar uma publicação nova e usar o método add.

```
 Publication pub = new Publication();
 //Set atributos...
 publications.add(pub);
```